# Printing a list of tuples without square brackets in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to print out a list of tuples without **square** brackets whilst maintaining parentheses around the tuple.

For example, instead of the output being (current output):

```
[('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4')]
```

The output should be:

```
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

*Current source code below.*

```
from itertools import product

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_lists = []
    num_loops = int(input())
    i = 0

    while i < num_loops:
        add_to_list = input()
        input_lists.append(add_to_list.split(" "))
        i += 1

    result = ([i for i in product(*input_lists)])
    print(''.join(str(result)))
```

Comment: What happens if you do `print(str(result[0]))`?

Comment: How about something simple like `re.sub(r"['\[\]]", '', str(lst))`?

Comment: @MattCremeens I get the output ('1', '3'), you may be onto something here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the `int` conversion and then unpack:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  # for Python 2
>>> lst = [('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4')]
>>> print(*[tuple(map(int,t)) for t in lst])
(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension, `str.format` and `str.join`:

```
In [1045]: lst = [('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4')]

In [1046]: ' '.join('({}, {})'.format(i, j) for i, j in lst)
Out[1046]: '(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)'
```

Comment: assumes the tuples are always only 2 elements though

Answer (score 1):

```
print(' '.join([str(int(i for i in tup)
                for tup in list_of_tuples]))
```

Calling `str()` on a tuple produces the tuple itself, really, so I just did this for each item in the list. I also needed to make each item in the tuple an int so I also performed `int()` on each item in each tuple. The `' '.join()` method will separate all of the items in the iterable passed in by a single whitespace. So... I passed in a list comprehension which performs `str()` on each item in the list.

Comment: This supports any number of tuples with any number of numbers in them. Obviously you'd have to remove the int() part if some items aren't an integer

Answer (score 0):

With an array like

```
 x = [('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4')]
```

you can do simply:

```
l = [(int(x),int(y)) for x,y in l]
print(*l)
```

Its output is similar to

```
output//(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
print(' '.join([str(tuple(map(int, i))) for i in L]))
```

A couple of points:

- We use `tuple` with `map` to convert values from `str` to `int`.
- `str.join` is one of the few instances where passing a list is more efficient than generator comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the list.

```
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(*lst)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) (3, 4)
```